# Creating an option scene and passing value to next scene with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an option scene that saves the value into a variable and goes on to the next option scene. [image: Option 2 is selected which is redirected to option 2's sub options]

Option 2 is selected which is redirected to option 2's sub options. 
Also all options have a value which is saved in a variable e.g. option 1 = value 0.5 option 2 = 0.75.
But I'm having a hard time Googling this. 
I was thinking in creating this is Javascript. I think that is the best option to code it with. 
Could you guys help me with getting the initial set of options? I'm also using HTML and CSS for my site.

Comment: Well, your choices for programming on the web are JavaScript, and languages that can compile to JavaScript, and possibly Web Assembly, if you're only targeting modern browsers. Stack Overflow, however, is a site where volunteers come to answer practical problems pertaining to software programming, not a "write me an example" work order. Please at least try and get the initial set of options looking how you want them, and how you want the sub-options to look, and we can help with the transition. Or, if you want help with getting the initial set of options, just ask about that.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm new to Stack Overflow. That's indeed exactly what I want, help with an initial set of options!

Comment: Show code, get answers how to fix it. :)